# Is there a way in PHP to escape a block of text?

Tags: php, string, escaping

Is there a way to tell PHP that this whole block of text is a pure text string (to escape the block and ignore everything inside)? 
eg. something like:

```
$myText= PHP_Magical_Start_String(
 ( for () This" ~' var is ´ my `&lt; |'| $complicated/"/ text{ echo }\ 
      "b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; *#text.§§ ) i==0. etc 
)PHP_Magical_End_String;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [nowdoc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc) to do the above

```php
$myText = <<<'EOT'
( for () This" ~' var is ´ my `&lt; |'| $complicated/"/ text{ echo }\ 
      "b&gt;bold&lt;/b&gt; *#text.§§ ) i==0. etc 
EOT;
```